# Failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:

Tags: npm, ionic2

I am installing "cordova-plugin-geolocation" via npm but "cordova-plugin-geolocation" is unable to install. I am seeing the following warnings:

> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
>
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14

Is there any possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

I used the following command to install NPM dependencies with the parameter NO-OPTIONAL

```
npm install --no-optional
```

source:
https://github.com/ariesjia/grunt-riot/issues/16

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Make `.npmignore` with 

`node_modules
chokidar/fsevents`
 inside

Comment: It looks like this is your first answer. Please edit your question to expand on your solution more and explain yourself a little further. Short one to two word answers generally don't fly on SO since they are not intended to help only the original user, but also everyone else who might get here through a search engine.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this error when I run gulp command

```
Error: watch node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss ENOSPC
        at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
        at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
        at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
        at createFsWatchInstance
```

I ran this and it works for me

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```